# Blazor the type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I have setup the basic application in Blazor in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.1.3 and I have tried both of the versions of .NET Core SDK 3.0.100-preview5-011568 and SDK 3.0.100-preview6-012264.

Also I have installed the Blazor extension but when I am building without any modification in any files, the build fails with the following error:

> "The type or namespace "App" could not be found.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There was something that changed in preview6 about App, check out the [release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/). In what version did you start your Project? What happens with a fresh new Project?

Comment: I get same error after upgrading project from .net 5 to 6 when using VS2019. For me, upgrading to the latest VS (2022/17) does eliminate the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use Blazor you need to have VS2019 preview edition or enable preview features on VS2019 by checking

> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features -> Use previews of the .NET Core SDK

or on the older versions of VS2019

> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> .NET Core -> Use previews of the .NET Core SDK

checkbox, then reload the solution and build.

Comment: I fixed this by upgrading to .NET version 3.0.100 using [dotnet-install.sh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/.NET_Core).

Comment: And for Visual Code?

Comment: I am using VS 2019 community, I followed above steps, still *Blazor App* option not shown. Please help

Comment: In my case, I had a reference to a preview version of a nuget package. So enabling Use previews of the .NET Core SDK resolves the issue

Answer (score 15):

For me, Blazor app was building locally, but not in Azure pipeline.

Adding App.razor.cs solved the build problem.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorDemo.Client
{
    public partial class App : ComponentBase
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

The error I got (using Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.2 & .NET 5 in a Blazor Server App) was pointing to the "App" part of the line above (in the file _Host.cshtml).
This happened after copying in some code from another project, and encountering issues with a different (application) namespace, I got this error (and no others) when trying to build. @SᴇM's answer helped me solve the problem - **I closed and re-opened my solution**, and then got namespace errors when building - which I could resolve... after fixing that it worked.

*I would have commented to @SᴇM's solution, but I don't have enough 'reputation'.*

Comment: I checked the namespace for App.razor (file is in the same project). Namespace is that of the project. I added that to "_Hosts". "using [project's namespace];

Answer (score 4):

Adding this line to .csproj fixed it for me.

```
<RootNamespace>MyBlazorApp</RootNamespace>
```

It can also be set on the Properties page, under "Default namespace".

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Using VS 2022 17.4. YMMV on previous versions. Not tested.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to @SᴇM answer, please make sure you are using latest version of Visual studio. For my case, I followed the same steps mentioned by @SᴇM but still option **Blazor App** option not shown.

After that, I updated visual studio to 16.3.7 and now option is visible while creating new project. :)

Answer (score 2):

After migrating my .NET Core 3.1 application to .NET 5.0 I experienced the same problem. My application was working just fine but since I opened my App.razor file errors showed.

"the type or namespace name 'pageName' could not be found" and the pages show normally.

Fixed the problem with Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features -> Use previews of the .NET Core SDK.
Restart of Visual Studio and reloading project was also needed.

Which is kind of weird since I just moved to .NET 5.0

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was the namespace definition in _Host.cshtml. Renaming it to the correct namespace solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Restart Visual Studio worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30104177)

Comment: @GhostOps, I disagree - I am using VS 17.2.3 and encountered this error after switching between startup projects. Restarting visual studio fixed the issue immediately so the answer is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a generic message that the compilation has failed. In my case the Error List was not useful, but Build Output had more information (search for "error") but it only had a partial hint:

> warning CS8785: Generator 'RazorSourceGenerator' failed to generate
> source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors
> may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'KeyNotFoundException'

It was still not enough, so I right-clicked the solution and chose "open in terminal" and there I executed this command manually:

> dotnet build

And this one gave me some more information about the actual key not being found  ("TableItem" in my case). This led me to some trial and error and I had some conflicting libraries (custom copy of BlazorTable and a new nuget version of MudBlazor) with similar component names.

```
I renamed <Table> to <BlazorTable>, and later to <BlaTable> 
(and ended up using <BlazorTable.BlaTable> to avoid repeating the namespace in class name)
```

Since I was still getting errors, I also removed all "@using BlazorTable" and instead included namespace in all tags, including attribute values in enum cases:

```
<BlazorTable.BlaTable TableItem="BillPlanListModel"
    Items=Rows 
    SelectionType=BlazorTable.SelectionType.Single>
        <BlazorTable.Column TableItem="BillPlanListModel" />
</BlazorTable.BlaTable>
```

This was a bit painful but it helped in my case after a few hours of work, and now I could upgrade MudBlazor to a new version. I was using .net 6 in VS2022, and got this error when updating MudBlazor from 6.02 to 6.03 (and later I was able to update MudBlazor to 6.0.10).

Comment: I didn't get any errors with `dotnet build` but rather it just built everything without issues. While that won't help me fix any of my issues with VS, it at least enables me to do work for now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I had the following package reference in my csproj file:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />`

Removing this fixed the issue.

The following output in my build.log file helped me track this down

```
1>/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets(404,5): warning RAZORSDK1006: Detected Razor language version downgrade. This is typically caused by a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design package. Consider removing this package reference.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me adding the namespace with a using statement worked.

```
@using PieShopHrmClientWebAssembly.App.Shared
```

Here PieShopHrmClientWebAssembly.App is my Blazor project name.

Answer (score 1):

My IDE (Rider) had added an `<ItemGroup>` tag with a couple of files (with the `<AdditionalFiles>` tag) in the csproj after doing some cleanup in the project. Removing those fixed the issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error while building a Blazor project and was able to resolve this by only keeping one major version of each .NET SDK.

Before I had installed:

- .NET 5 SDK
- .NET 6 SDK
- .NET 7.0.4xx SDK
- .NET 7.0.1xx SDK

Different major and minor versions of the SDK are kept side by side. Keeping only one .NET 7 SDK (in my case I removed version 7.0.4xx) resolved the error.

**Full context:**
I had multiple .NET 7 SDK's because I was using an LTSC version of Visual Studio 2022: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs-servicing#long-term-servicing-channel-ltsc-support

My version of Visual Studio 2022 (17.4) was using 7.0.1xx, but I also had installed a newer version of it mistakenly. When VS was building my solution it was using the newest SDK version instead of it's own, which had minor compatibility issues with the source generator; it was giving me build warnings that read like:
`Warning CS9057  The analyzer assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.307\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\source-generators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll' references version '4.6.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.4.0.0'.`

If you look under installed programs, it should list the Visual Studio version of the SDK as something like **Microsoft .NET SDK 7.0.110 from Visual Studio**. This is the version that VS should be using, but it seemed to be confused with the newer (7.0.4xx) version installed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jonno answer, if you copy razor files you need to change Build Action to Content in File Properties

Answer (score 0):

Renaming my project from "App" to "GCL-App" worked for me, as it is throwing "circular dependency issue inclusive of the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and restarting Visual Studio 2019 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing so code cleanup, including removing unneeded using statements and started getting this error.  I (or a tool) removed the site usings from the _Imports.razor fixed it.

Adding

```
@using {Site.Client}
@using {Site.Client}.Shared
```

back to my _Imports.razor fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Blazor, I was getting this error and fretting about namespaces.  It turned out that I had a malformed tag in a page:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="@(() => SetActivity("Office"))>Office</button>
```

(note missing quotation marks in the onclick event)

This was enough to produce this apparently unconnected error (though Rider had gently underlined the closing button tag indicating it wasn't closing anything it understood).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Visual Studio to the latest version fixed it for me.