# blazor intellisense not working visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, blazor

I am currently using `Visual studio community 2019 version 16.1.3` I created a new web application - Blazor.  I have made no changes to this new application.

Everything blazor related is showing up with the red line and

> Error  CS0103  The name 'currentCount' does not exist in the current context

[image]

The application does run though.  Am i missing something to be able to use the intellisense with blazor?

Comment: Its something to do with the versioning of VS and Blazor. Try install the latest Blazor template and upgrade to `2019 16.1.4`. Old Blazor projects will also have this issue, best bet is to just use the new template and migrate them manually. You'll also need the Core 3.0 latest preview SDK and then run this: `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview6.19307.2` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: You may need to use a preview version of VS.

Comment: @DavidG I think OP is going to answer to own question. Otherwise, to use new Blazor features, you need to enable preview features from `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features -> Use previews of the .NET Core SDK`.

Comment: SDK Version SDK Version: 3.0.100-preview6-012264

Comment: @DavidG Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think you need the preview versions in the latest builds of VS, I don't seem to have any issues with it using the latest preview templates.

Comment: @SᴇM nope OP has been trying to figure this out since yesterday and is at a loss.  This is a new install of the PC.  I was wondering if it was some setting in visual studio i am missing.

Comment: @DaImTo Did you tried to enable _preview features_? Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56576553/blazor-the-type-or-namespace-name-app-could-not-be-found-are-you-missing-a-us/56576992#56576992).

Comment: @DaImTo You'll also need to create new projects form the CLI as the templates in VS aren't the right version.

Comment: @SᴇM i enabled the one that I need to get it to pick up .net core 3.0 is there another?

Comment: @DaImTo Nope, I'm not saying it will solve intellisense problem (It'll solve buld/run problem, sorry I've missed last part of your question), it will not, as DavidG stated, for that, you need a preview version of VS.

Comment: Heres where i say that i assumed someone had forgotten to update the line where it said **Install the latest Visual Studio preview with the ASP.NET and web development workload.**

Comment: @KieranDevlin I'm pretty sure you need the preview to get a smooth dev experience, and that includes error like this.

Comment: Downloading the preview now.  I tried with the cli and have the same problem..

Comment: @DaImTo Someone said [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5669#issuecomment-490012221), that _"For ASP.NET Core 3.0 Preview 4 and newer, you need Visual Studio 2019 16.1 Preview. 16.0 will work for building, but not for IntelliSense, etc."_

Comment: You guys rock! It works. Thanks so much.  Someone want to pop that into an answer?

Comment: Not sure it's worth answering really, after all when core 3 is released properly, this question will no longer be relevant.

Comment: I'm facing this issue with latest .NET Core 3.0 release and VS 2019 v16.3.0 - both are latest available versions. Does anyone know how to get intellisense working in Blazor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that at the time of this question Blazor is still not released. I had installed Visual studio 2019 which did have blazor support but unfortunately the in intellisense only worked in Visual studio 2019 preview.

This is the anwser that was given in one of the comments above.

Answer (score 2):

Updating to the latest preview version is what fixed it for me.