# Blazor WebAssembly project, Intellisense pops an error : the type or namespace name 'App' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I'm trying to use Blazor WebAssembly.
I create a project and the code isL

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app"); // Error there : The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

        builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

As I comment in the code, App is not found by intellisense and an error is shown. I can't use f12 on the word "App" (unfound).
I can build and launch the project but I want to clean it properly.

I followed this thread : [Blazor the type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56576553/blazor-the-type-or-namespace-name-app-could-not-be-found-are-you-missing-a-us) but it didn't fix it.

My IDE is Visual Studio Community : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6.2 and dotnet --version gives : 5.0.100-preview.6.20318.15

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure that all the packages using by your project has been updated and compatible with .net 5.

Updating these two packages resolved the issue for me:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I find it is the problem about the version of vs.

I suggest that you use the latest vs2019 preview to open it.

I used the following vs2019 preview version without any problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I install the preview version right now and I test

Comment: It is working very well in preview. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, after I install some extensions to VS 2019 preview the bug is back. I'm looking for the one who provokes this error.

Answer (score 0):

As Jack J Jun suggested, I installed the preview version of VS.
It worked. But as soon as I install the extension CodeMaid, the error came back. When I deactivated CodeMaid, the error disappeared.

Comment: Yep, I uninstalled Codemaid completely and error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code and for some reason if you want to change name space of your Blazor project you need to inherit App class from Component base and and include it same namespace with Program class.

Reason of getting this weird error must be not finding the hidden  or "virtual" App class somewhere.
Adding this one line of code also resolves the error as well.

I'm putting App class same file with Program class like following since it's just one line of code.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace YourNameSpace;

internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}

partial class App : ComponentBase { }
```

All credit goes to [Nemanja Stolic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11719831/nemanja-stolic) who answered similar similar question [Blazor the type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56576553/blazor-the-type-or-namespace-name-app-could-not-be-found-are-you-missing-a-us)